# Dynamicly change TYPO3 fluid Layout by typeNum

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.1.x, flux

I am using the extension fluidpages and want to switch the layout by the typeNum.
is it possible to change the f:layout by by an condition?
This wont work:

```
<f:layout name="{f:if(condition: '{typeNum} == 666', then: 'PageAjax', else: 'Page')}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested approach:

`<f:layout name="Page/{typeNum}"/>`

Required files:

- Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/0.html
- Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/666.html

Please note: this only works if the {typeNum} variable is guaranteed to exist - if it does not, you will face a "template file not found" error with an empty filename. To avoid this, you can use the VHS extension's `v:var.convert` ViewHelper to ensure a proper value:

`<f:layout name="Page/{typeNum -> v:var.convert(type: 'integer')}"/>`

Comment: This does not explain why the above does not work. It would be good to know, in order to handle similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem recently, and found the solution after a few researchings.

The problem is, you can not use nested fluid like `<f:if>`, `<f:cObject>` or others in `<f:layout>`. Otherwise, you will get a fatal error in the cache file, saying `call to a member function getViewHelper() on a non-object.` And when you look at the cache file, you will find it's because `$self` is not defined.

Therefore, my solution is, searching `public function getLayoutName(` in \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Compiler\TemplateCompiler, and adding `\$self = \$this;` before `\$currentVariableContainer = \$renderingContext->getTemplateVariableContainer();`, just like `generateCodeForSection()`

Answer (score 0):

I have now added the Condition in the Layout template. I get the typeNum from typoscript.

```
<f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'plugin.nc_template.settings.pageLayout')} == 'Default'">
<p>Default Template</p>
</f:if>

<f:if condition="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'plugin.nc_template.settings.pageLayout')} == 'Ajax'">
    <p>Ajax Template</p>
</f:if>
```

I found an example on the fedext Page, but could not get this to run:
[https://fedext.net/blog/archive.html?tx_news_pi1[news]=55&tx_news_pi1[%40widget_0][currentPage]=8&cHash=f9c3165598a28d2aa98fd30ef115bb75](https://fedext.net/blog/archive.html?tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=55&tx_news_pi1%5B@widget_0%5D%5BcurrentPage%5D=8&cHash=f9c3165598a28d2aa98fd30ef115bb75)

Answer (score -2):

Can´t you use an if-statement instead?
IMHO this is easier to read - and if you need to add more arguments which depends on typeNum, it would stay readable.

```
<f:if condition="{typeNum} == 666">
  <f:then>
    <f:layout name="PageAjax">
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    <f:layout name="Page">
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Comment: I just took the inline if condition. But it does'nt matter if i take the tag-based or the inline writing. I think i do not have access to the fluid if viewhelper in the f:layout section.

Comment: This will not work - the reason being that the value of the `f:layout` node is processed without actually rendering the template.